# trying to reverse a string inplace using two pointers

Tags: c, pointers

```
#include<conio.h>          
#include<stdio.h>    

int main(void)    
{    
    char str[20];    
    char *ptr1,*ptr2;    
    printf("Enter string\n");    
    gets(str);    
    ptr1,ptr2=&str[0];    
    while(*ptr2!='\0')                  
    {    
        ptr2++;    
    }    
    ptr2--;    
    printf("rev_string =");    
    while(ptr1!=ptr2)    //this should work for when strlen=odd integer
    {    
        int temp=*ptr2;    
        *ptr2=*ptr1;    
        *ptr1=temp;    
        ptr1++;    
        ptr2--;    
     }    
    puts(str);    
    return 0;    
}
```

---

whats wrong with my code?i know the condtion which i've put into the while loop is not gonna work when length of the string is even but it should work for odd cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems there is a typo

```
'#include<conio.h>          
^^
```

The C standard does not support any more function `gets`. Instead you should use standard function `fgets`.

This condition

```
while(ptr1!=ptr2)
```

is wrong for strings with an even number of characters because it will be never equal to false and the loop will be infinite.

The following statement is also wrong

```
ptr1,ptr2=&str[0];
```

Here is used the comma operator and ptr1 is not initialized.

I think you mean

```
ptr1 = ptr2 = &str[0];
```

The program can be written the following way

```
#include<stdio.h>    

int main( void )    
{    
    char str[20];    
    char *ptr1,*ptr2;

    printf( "Enter a string: ");    
    fgets( str, sizeof( str ), stdin );

    ptr2 = str;

    while ( *ptr2 != '\0' ) ++ptr2;                  

    if ( ptr2 != str && *( ptr2 - 1 ) == '\n' ) *--ptr2 = '\0';

    printf( "rev_string = " );    

    ptr1 = str;

    if ( ptr1 != ptr2 )
    {
        for ( ; ptr1 < --ptr2; ++ptr1 )
        {    
            int temp = *ptr2;    
            *ptr2 = *ptr1;    
            *ptr1 = temp;
        }    
    }

    puts( str );

    return 0;    
}
```

Comment: yes, i already mentioned that condition (ptr1!=ptr2) is not gonna work for even length of strings but it should work for odd ones, just want to know why it didn't  work for odd lengths also.

Comment: can u tell me pls why u did this?                                                                                      if ( ptr2 != str && *( ptr2 - 1 ) == '\n' ) *--ptr2 = '\0';

Comment: @Prince Vijay Pratap Function fgets includes the new line character in the target string that corresponds to the pressed key Enter. You should remove it.